# How do place an image to the side of a cube using the Python API

Tags: python

I am trying to map an image to the side of a cube (just one side) and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with the PythonAPI.

I tried something similar to this: [tutorial](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Materials_and_textures) but it warps the image so that it covers the whole cube.

The reason I'd like to use the python api is that I'm going to be doing this for thousands of images. It would be nice not to do it by hand :)

Any help/tips/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you could use the "import images as planes" addon, and then just extrude them as cubes. If this would work for you and you need a Howto, let me know

Comment: Can you UV unwrap the cube by hand before using python?

Answer (score 1):

Here is python code which might serve as a start: http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/texture-one-cube-face.html

```
import bpy


def apply_image_to_face(template, fname):
    imgs = [ img for img in bpy.data.images if img.type=='IMAGE' and img.filepath==fname]
    if len(imgs)<1:
        img = bpy.data.images.load(fname)
        print(img.name)
    else:
        img = imgs[0]

    tex = bpy.data.textures.new(fname, 'IMAGE')
    tex.image = img

    obj = bpy.data.objects.new("capybara", template.data)

    mat = template.data.materials[1].copy()

    tslot = mat.texture_slots[0]
    if tslot is None:
        tslot = mat.texture_slots.add()
    tslot.texture = tex
    tslot.texture_coords = 'UV'

    obj.material_slots[1].link = 'OBJECT'
    print(obj.material_slots[1].link)
    obj.material_slots[1].material = mat
    print("argh "+obj.material_slots[1].link)

    return obj


# this needs to be the template object.
# It needs to already have a UV map.
# The first texture slot is for most of the cube.
# The second texture slot must exist and we will fill it with a newly-created material for the image
# one of the faces must already be assigned this second material.
template = bpy.data.objects["template"]
# template = bpy.context.active_object

obj = apply_image_to_face(template, "/home/thoth/art/drawing-practice/totoro.png")
obj.location= (0,1,0)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
```

You have to have a template object named 'template'.  That object has to already have a UV map.  It has to have two materials.  The second material will be cloned to make the per-image materials.  At least one of the faces on the template object must use that second material (otherwise it never gets used to paint anything)

Blender 2.75a has a bug where when I set the `material_slot[1].link = 'OBJECT'` it does not stick.  It reverts to 'DATA' right after I assign material_slot[1](http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/meshFromBathymetry.html).material .  A fix for this is already in the tracker and will probably be in the next release of blender.

The code above would have to be adapted if you have your own RGB pixel data instead of a file in the filesystem.   Change out the part that does `bpy.data.images.load(fname)` with something like getGradientImage() from [this bathymetry script](http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/meshFromBathymetry.html):

```
def getGradientImage():
    """rainbow gradient image"""
    rval = bpy.data.images.get("gradient")
#    print(rval)
    if rval is None:
        rval = bpy.data.images.new("gradient", 1, 6)

        rval.pixels = [
            #R,G,B,A,
            1,0,1,1, # magenta
            0,0,1,1, # blue
            0,1,1,1, # cyan
            0,1,0,1, # green
            1,1,0,1, # yellow
            1,0,0,1, # red
        ]
        # if we don't pack the image into the .blend, it will be lost when you re-load the project
        rval.pack(True)
    return rval
```

Of course, you'll want to give each data set its own image name instead of "gradient".

Comment: And https://developer.blender.org/T45695 will track the bug.

Comment: Nice starter code! Are aware of any way to directly do this if I have a numpy array representing the image? I'd rather avoid saving the numpy image as a png everything I want to use this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to UV unwrap the cube first, and then create 2 materials for the cube. Apply 1 material to the single face that you want the texture on, and the second material to the other 5 faces. Once that is set up, it should be trivial to update the image texture on the 1 face via python.

Comment: This sounds like a super reasonable approach... I will give it a try!

Comment: Ok, let me know how it goes!

Comment: I got this to work roughly, using a bit of the code from above. Thanks!