# How to add six PNG Images to a cube in a Python Script

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

How can i add six different PNG Images as textures to a cube with a Python Script?
I have a cube and i want to apply an image to each of the six sides.
For example if i would like to render a dice, then i would Need six different textures with 1 dot up to 6 dots.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: May I ask why Python Script and not UV map? I'm really curious about such method.

And something raleted: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34930/how-do-place-an-image-to-the-side-of-a-cube-using-the-python-api

Comment: What have you got so far?